# Who publishes the default DNS discovery list

Tags: dns

Geth v1.9.11 introduced support for [DNS discovery](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1459). According to [the code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/38d1b0cba277db17129a4870158115c5a428cffc/params/bootnodes.go#L75-L84), the default DNS list is hosted on ethdisco.net. See also: https://github.com/ethereum/discv4-dns-lists

Who publishes this list and who has access to the private keys with which this list is signed?

Answer (score 1):

This is the tool which does the crawling: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/cmd/devp2p

Then it's published by the Geth team.